# Get all array elements except for a specific value in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way I can get all array elements **except** for a specific value given by the user?

**I am using C# Language for my Unity program.**

Comment: What code have you tried??

Comment: `arr.Except(x=>somecondition).ToArray()`

Comment: @LeiYang Except needs an IEnumerable, not a Func.

Comment: where do you know it is a Func?

Comment: @Hristo I haven't tried any codes for now because I am thinking of ways on how to do that. What I have in mind is to create another array to handle other elements but it will not be efficient.

Comment: @LeiYang that is not applicable because Except needs an IEnumerable

Comment: you mention **array elements** and you say it is not IEnumerable?

Comment: @LeiYang your code should be `Where`, not `Except`. `Except` works with two `IEnumerables` (`arr.Except(arr2)`). It should be `arr.Where(x => x != userValue)`

Comment: yes you're right, i made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```
  // remove where not is "1"
  string[] arr = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
  string[] all = arr.Where(x => (x != "1")).ToArray();

  // or remove by index
  int numIndex = Array.IndexOf(arr, "1");
  arr = arr.Where((val, idx) => idx != numIndex).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am using Unity and this code doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work c# is c# also in unity? (in my program it does work)

Comment: @soNice Do not forget to include `using System.Linq;` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
public T[] Except<T>(T[] array, T specificValue) where T : IComparable {
            return array.Where<T>(val => val.CompareTo(specificValue) != 0).ToArray();
        }
```